# Could not load file or assembly MySql.data error when invoking VB.net application

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I made an application in **Visual Studio 2013** using VB.net that works with my MySql database.
the program compiles and runs well when invoked through visual studio. However, when I run the application in the debug folder, I get the following error.

[image]

I have.

1. copied the MySql.data dll to the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
   and referenced my project to that dll. -> ***Error does not go away.***
2. i set local to true for this dll in VS -> ***Error does not go away.***

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a similar problem. For your application to run, you need to install the MySQL DotNet Connector msi. here is the link https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.9.8.msi. Download and install. Your application should now run ok